# Rendering dropdown using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

From the Api call im getting response like this:-

```
[
    {
        "Product.Name": "Data Migration - Test1",
        "Product.Id": "8ad0",
        "Product.Hello__c": {
            "Value": "First",
            "type": "string",
            "picklist": [
                "First",
                "Second"
            ],
            "Required": false,
            "UIReadOnly": false
        },
        "Product.Category": "Base Products",
        "is_Product_Duplicate": false,
        "is_ProductRatePlan_Duplicate": false,
        "is_ProductRatePlanCharge_Duplicate": false,
        "is_ProductRatePlanChargeTier_Duplicate": false
    }
]
```

im trying to render this json in the api call like this:-

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setErrorMessage([]);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          ${API_ENDPOINT}/fetch-product-catalog-ui/${tenantId},
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + user.accessToken,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
          }
        );
        if (response.status === 401) {
          localStorage.clear();
          window.location.href = "/zuorahelperclient/login";
          return;
        }
        if (response.status === 400) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setError({ error: data.Errors[0].Message });
        } else if (response.ok) {
          const resultJson = await response.json();
          const updatedData = resultJson.map((row, index) => {
            const processedRow = { ...row, rowId: index + 1 };
            for (const prop in processedRow) {
              const propValue = processedRow[prop];
              if (typeof propValue === "object" && "Value" in propValue) {
                processedRow[prop] = propValue.Value; //here it reads and displays the value
                if (
                  propValue.type === "string" &&
                  Array.isArray(propValue.picklist)
                ) {
                  console.log(Column Name: ${prop}, Type: ${propValue.type});
                  console.log(Picklist Values: ${propValue.picklist.join(", ")}`
                  );
                }
              }
            }

            return processedRow;
          });
          setData(updatedData);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
      }
    };

    fetchData();}, []);
```

In the table cell, im trying to add the picklist values as dropdown for the user to edit, but the condition is not being verified in the first place, here is the piece of return statement:-

```
{Object.keys(row).map((columnName, columnIndex) => {
                          if (
                            columnName !== "Product.Id" &&
                            columnName !== "is_Product_Duplicate" &&
                            columnName !== "is_ProductRatePlan_Duplicate" &&
                            columnName !==
                              "is_ProductRatePlanCharge_Duplicate" &&
                            columnName !==
                              "is_ProductRatePlanChargeTier_Duplicate"
                          ) {
                            console.log(
                              "Rendering cell for column:",
                              columnName
                            );
                            console.log("row[columnName]:", row[columnName]);
                            console.log(
                              "typeof row[columnName].type:",
                              typeof row[columnName].type
                            );
                            console.log("Row Value:", row[columnName]);
                            console.log(
                              "Is Array:",
                              Array.isArray(row[columnName]?.picklist)
                            );
                            return (
                              <TableCell key={columnName}>
                                {editMode ? (
                                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    {columnName === "Product.Category" ? (
                                      <select
                                        value={row[columnName]}
                                        onChange={(event) =>
                                          handleValueChange(
                                            event,
                                            rowIndex,
                                            columnName
                                          )
                                        }
                                        disabled={row.is_Product_Duplicate}
                                        style={{
                                          padding: "8px",
                                          fontSize: "16px",
                                          width: "200px",
                                          borderRadius: "1px",
                                          border: "none",
                                          borderBottom:
                                            columnName === "Product.Category"
                                              ? "1px dotted grey"
                                              : "1px solid #000000",
                                          fontWeight: editedRows.has(row)
                                            ? "normal"
                                            : "normal",
                                          backgroundColor: editedRows.has(row)
                                            ? "#f3f3f3"
                                            : "inherit",
                                        }}
                                      >
                                        {categoryValues.map((category) => (
                                          <option
                                            key={category.value}
                                            value={category.value}
                                          >
                                            {category.label}
                                          </option>
                                        ))}
                                      </select>
                                    ) : typeof row[columnName] === "object" &&
                                      row[columnName]?.type === "string" &&
                                      Array.isArray(
                                        row[columnName]?.picklist
                                      ) ? (
                                      <React.Fragment>
                                        {console.log(
                                          "Inside  condition"
                                        )}
                                        <select
                                          value={row[columnName].Value}
                                          onChange={(event) =>
                                            handleValueChange(
                                              event,
                                              rowIndex,
                                              columnName
                                            )
                                          }
                                          disabled={
                                            !editMode ||
                                            row[
                                              `is_${
                                                columnName.split(".")[0]
                                              }_Duplicate`
                                            ]
                                          }
                                          style={{
                                            padding: "8px",
                                            fontSize: "16px",
                                            width: "200px",
                                            borderRadius: "1px",
                                            border: "none",
                                            fontWeight: editedRows.has(row)
                                              ? "normal"
                                              : "normal",
                                            backgroundColor: editedRows.has(row)
                                              ? "#f3f3f3"
                                              : "inherit",
                                          }}
                                        >
                                          {row[columnName].picklist.map(
                                            (option) => (
                                              <option
                                                key={option}
                                                value={option}
                                              >
                                                {option}
                                              </option>
                                            )
                                          )}
                                        </select>
                                      </React.Fragment>
                                    ) : columnName ===
                                      "ProductRatePlanCharge.RevenueRecognitionRuleName" ? (
                                      <select
                                        value={row[columnName]}
                                        onChange={(event) =>
                                          handleValueChange(
                                            event,
                                            rowIndex,
                                            columnName
                                          )
                                        }
                                        disabled={row.is_Product_Duplicate}
                                        style={{
                                          fontSize: "16px",
                                          padding: "8px",
                                          width: "200px",
                                          borderRadius: "1px",
                                          border: "none",
                                          borderBottom:
                                            columnName ===
                                            "ProductRatePlanCharge.RevenueRecognitionRuleName"
                                              ? "1px dotted grey"
                                              : "1px solid #000000",
                                          fontWeight: editedRows.has(row)
                                            ? "normal"
                                            : "normal",
                                          backgroundColor: editedRows.has(row)
                                            ? "#f3f3f3"
                                            : "inherit",
                                        }}
                                      >
                                        {revenuerecognitionrulenameValues.map(
                                          (revenuerecognitionrulename) => (
                                            <option
                                              key={
                                                revenuerecognitionrulename.value
                                              }
                                              value={
                                                revenuerecognitionrulename.value
                                              }
                                            >
                                              {revenuerecognitionrulename.label}
                                            </option>
                                          )
                                        )}
                                      </select>
                                    ) : (
                                      <TextField
                                        value={row[columnName]}
                                        onChange={(event) =>
                                          handleValueChange(
                                            event,
                                            rowIndex,
                                            columnName
                                          )
                                        }
                                        disabled={
                                          !editMode ||
                                          row[
                                            `is_${
                                              columnName.split(".")[0]
                                            }_Duplicate`
                                          ]
                                        }
                                        inputProps={{
                                          style: {
                                            fontSize: "16px",
                                            padding: "10px 20px",
                                          },
                                        }}
                                        style={{
                                          fontWeight: editedRows.has(row)
                                            ? "bold"
                                            : "normal",
                                          backgroundColor: editedRows.has(row)
                                            ? "#f3f3f3"
                                            : "inherit",
                                        }}
                                      />
                                    )}
                                  </div>
                                ) : (
                                  <span>
                                    {columnName.includes("EffectiveStart") ||
                                    columnName.includes("EffectiveEnd")
                                      ? new Date(
                                          row[columnName]
                                        ).toLocaleDateString()
                                      : row[columnName]}
                                  </span>
                                )}
                              </TableCell>
                            );
                          }

                          return null;
                        })}
```

Tried consoling, found that this condition "typeof row[columnName] === "object" && row[columnName]?.type === "string" && Array.isArray( row[columnName]?.picklist) " it self is not being verified, here is the image of console statements,[console statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lou3j.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should destructure your code with the if condition (instead of the ternary operator).
[Helpful docs](https://medium.com/@benlmsc/stop-using-nested-ternary-operators-heres-why-53e7e078e65a)

You should see "found it" log with the below code.

```
const arr = {
"Product.Name": "Data Migration - Test1",
"Product.Id": "8ad0",
"Product.Hello__c": {
  Value: "First",
  type: "string",
  picklist: ["First", "Second"],
  Required: false,
  UIReadOnly: false,
},
"Product.Category": "Base Products",
is_Product_Duplicate: false,
is_ProductRatePlan_Duplicate: false,
is_ProductRatePlanCharge_Duplicate: false,
is_ProductRatePlanChargeTier_Duplicate: false,
};

Object.keys(row).map((columnName, columnIndex) => {

const isColumnIncluded = [
  "Product.Id",
  "is_Product_Duplicate",
  "is_ProductRatePlan_Duplicate",
  "is_ProductRatePlanCharge_Duplicate",
  "is_ProductRatePlanChargeTier_Duplicate",
].includes(columnName);
if (!isColumnIncluded) {
  console.log("Rendering cell for column:", columnName);
  console.log("row[columnName]:", row[columnName]);
  console.log("typeof row[columnName].type:", typeof row[columnName].type);
  console.log("Row Value:", row[columnName]);
  console.log("Is Array:", Array.isArray(row[columnName]?.picklist));
  if (
    typeof row[columnName] === "object" &&
    row[columnName]?.type === "string" &&
    Array.isArray(row[columnName]?.picklist)
  ) {
    console.log("found it");
  } else {
    console.log("in else");
  }
}

return null;
});
```

Comment: thanks but destructuring  code with the if condition is also not working